# Python app in Azure app service: raise JavaError("can't find Java")

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to create a Python app in Azure App Service. The code involves module language-check, which requires Java. I am wondering how I could install Java in Azure App Service. Thanks!

Comment: My answer has been updated, creating a webapp and choosing linux will solve your problem. If you choose windows, there will be an error of installing language_check without permission (found during webjob testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

## It is recommended to choose linux platform to create web app.

Run below command in webssh.

> Step 1.  apt-get update

> Step 2.  apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk

> Step 3.  java -version

> Step 4. pip install language_check

[image]

After trying, I found in windows webapp that although the webapp contains a java environment, when executing `tool = language_check.LanguageTool('en-US')`, an error `language_check.JavaError: can't find Java` will be reported.

**In windows webapp.**

[image]
[image]

When you create a webapp, no matter what language environment you choose, when the creation is complete, in the azure web app, all language environments are included by default.

Suppose you create a webapp based on the node language of windows, then you can create virtual applications in other languages such as `java`, `.net`, `python` etc., all of which are supported, which I have tested.

Comment: Thanks you so much!! Sorry but I still have no idea about how to specify the correct Java path. Could you kindly help me with that, too? I tried to add java_path = 'C:\Program Files\JavaConfigTransformer\bin\java.exe' in the __init__.py of language_check. However, seems that it did not work. Really appreciate that.

Comment: @SuofeiWu You don't need to install java in azure web app. My answer just show you webapp you created has java environment.

Comment: @SuofeiWu Which platform you use, windows or linux ?

Comment: @SuofeiWu If you must use windows, it is recommended to use `Docker Container` to create a webapp.

Comment: @SuofeiWu In linux, you can try to install it by  `pip install language_check` manually. In windows,  I also try to run the command, but failed.

Comment: Thanks! Seems that I have some issue on connecting to the ssh. I will try to install language_check after fixing that. Thank you for your kind help.